# Passing objects between classes in Windows Phone/C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I'm new to Windows Phone and C#, enjoying the change from Objective-C and Java.

I cant find the way to pass an object from one class to another. I came across some sample code looking on MSDN but I tink that maybe its not applicable for what I need.

```
    private void meetingList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (meetingList.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            Meeting aMeeting = (Meeting)meetingList.SelectedItem;
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MeetDetails.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
        }
    }
```

How can I pass my Meeting Object 'aMeeting' into my MeetDetails class so that I can display all the details to the user.

I know I can break it down, and pass in all the vars from the 'aMeeting' by using something like this:

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MeetDetails.xaml?Meeting=" +
            aMeeting.meetName + "&TheDate=" +
            aMeeting.meetDate, UriKind.Relative));
```

Is there something I've missed? Are there alternative ways you guys would recommend?

Many Thanks,
-Code

Comment: check out : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/81ca8713-809a-4505-8422-000a42c30da8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
         var t1 = App.Current as App;
         t1.SSIDToken = stData1SSID;
         t1.CSRFToken = stData1CSRF;
```

this works real good, just make the members u need in the app.cs file 
(here it was :

public string SSIDToken {get; set;}
public string CSRFToken {get; set;}

Then create the top code to create a var to serve as temp buffer.
If you want to get back the values use the same code :

```
     var t1 = App.Current as App;
     thisisatextbox.Text = t1.SSIDToken;
     thisisalsoatextbox.Text = t1.CSRFToken;
```

Further info ; 
http://www.eugenedotnet.com/2011/07/passing-values-between-windows-phone-7-pages-current-context-of-application/

EDIT: After a couple of months of experience, noticed you can add

```
public static new App Current
{
    get { return Application.Current as App; }
}
```

In the App.xaml (In the public class App) to be able to call upon App.Current without having to declare it every single time!

Now you can use App.Current.CSRFToken = "" || string CSRFTk = App.Current.CSRFToken;

Answer (score 2):

What you've posted is a good way of transferring simple data about the place. However it becomes a pain when you have to pass a complex object between pages.

The recommended way is to use the MVVM pattern (from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)). This gives you a way to separate the View from everything else by making use of data binding. The best tutorials I have seen is to watch the [videos on MSDN](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmvideo1).

Comment: Thanks for the links gBanFill. I'll start to get through them. (video is pretty long). Is there something specific you can point me to that shows how to pass an object like in Objective-C or is this not supported in C# ? I'm pretty time constrained this week to experiement with a new design pattern.

Comment: The quickest way without learning mvvm pattern proper would be to add a property to the app class which you could set up before calling navigate then retrieve in page load. I don't know objective-c so can't help with that. On a train so can't point you to a specific part of video

Comment: Thanks gbanfill, I appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider a manager class with properties which could store your current Meeting object. This would then be set in your SelectionChanged event handler and then accessed in your MeetDetails page. The manager class is defined externally to your pages so that it can be accessed from all your pages.

Comment: Hi Paul, this is the method I considered going with to save me time because it is so simple. But I dont always want to reach for the easiest solution and never learn new methods. Thanks for your input.