# Windows Phone - Accessing a variable from another page

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I am creating a Windows Phone App which allows the user to post to twitter, however i have one page that is used to authorize the access to the persons twitter and it is on this page where several variables are given values. I then have another page where i let the user write and post the tweet, but in order to post it i need to be able to access these variables from the other page, how would i do this?

I have already tried to write something like:

```
Pagename.variablename
```

But it is inaccessible.

Also i am writing in VB.NET

Comment: I'll link to my previous answer :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206358/passing-objects-between-classes-in-windows-phone-c/10228182#10228182

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make variablename static. it means, declare it like this:

```
Public Shared variablename As String = ""
```

Then you can assign it and use it later from any where.

When you want to access it, you will need to add "&". For example:

```
MessageBox.Show("this is the variable" &PageName.variablename)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could declare the variable static like

```
public static int amount;
```

and now this static variable can be used anywhere with the class name.

Likewise declare a variable in app.xaml.cs

```
public static string VarName;
```

and this variavble can now be used anywhere in the app like

```
App.VarName= "Hello";
```